# 404 Error: localhost MAMP server cannot find javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, mamp

I am coding a PHP website homepage using a MAMP localhost server. I would like to connect the main HTML file to a javascript file, but when I do so, none of the javascript is executed, and an error that says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) appears.

I have tried using the absolute file path when including the file under the src attribute (though the js file is in the same folder as the main html file anyway). I tried turning the server on and off and reloading the page several times, but the error still appears.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/homescript.js"></script>
</head>

<body onresize="changeHeaderDisplay()" onload="responsiveCarousel()">
</body>
```

Comment: Is the error in the browser window (for the main HTML page) or in the console when it tries to load the JS asset? BTW - you're missing your `<html>` elements. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Unlikely with a 404, but maybe check the permissions for the .js file.  Usually should be 644.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slash at the beginning of the filename in the script tag is the problem :

`src="/homescript.js"`

When your browser sees a forward slash, it assumes the file is at the top level of the domain it's searching. So if your html file is at:

`file:///Users/Jack/test_program/index.html`

it is searching for homescript.js at:

`file:///homescript.js`

To make it search for it at:

`file:///Users/Jack/test_program/homescript.js`

simply remove the leading forward slash:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="homescript.js"></script>`

---

Edit: On a website, it's the same phenomenon:

With leading slash:
`http://www.example.com/homescript.js`

Without leading slash: `http://www.example.com/test_program/files/homescript.js`

Comment: thanks for the response! so if do not have a website running yet and I am just hosting it on a local MAMP server, would I specify the file path like so?: 'http://localhost:8888/Practice/Home/homescript.js'

Comment: @Jack try just `src="homescript.js"`